# How use index in a pointer with Struct and pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, realloc

I need to make a program that can register some car.
Then I need show all the cars registeres.

I can't make this work, when I execute the code below the printf show just memory trash, and just the last car appears right! 

Code (I have a menu function that call the others):

```
int id = 0;

struct car {

    char brand[50];
    char model[50];

};
car *garage = 0;
int doCar(){

    garage = (struct car *)malloc(sizeof(struct car*));
    printf("\n Insert the model: \n\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets( garage[id].model, 50, stdin);
    id++;

}

int ShowCars(){

    int i = 0;

    while (i < id) {

        printf("aqi= %s \n", garage[id].model);
        i++;

    }   

}
```

Comment: I try to use Realloc as well, but always appears the same error.

Comment: `car *garage = 0;` --> `struct car *garage = 0;` and `garage = (struct car *)malloc(sizeof(struct car*));` --> `garage =  (struct car *)malloc(sizeof(struct car));` and remove `fflush(stdin);`

Comment: This isn't really c++ at all

Comment: If i change garage = (struct car...
Show the error: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "car *"

Comment: This is C++, use `new` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: What does `doCar()` return? And how do you expect to see pointer to new car outside this function?

Comment: `sizeof(struct car*)` is a little bit too small to hold a `struct car`.

Comment: VolAnd, doCar() return NULL. I dont know, how i suppose to do?

Comment: As pointed out by others, in C++ you typically use `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`. However, I do not see a single reason why you use pointers. Using `std::string` instead of `char*`, `std::vector` instead of plain c-style array and using objects instead of pointers (when there is no need for pointers) can make your life so much easier.

Comment: Unfortunately i need to use malloc or realloc. My college teacher ask that way. Sorry :/

Comment: I don't see any C++ in this question, and it is not (or more precisely **no more**) tagged C++.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` yields in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct car {

    char brand[50];
    char model[50];

};

// dlobal variables
car* garage = NULL;
int cnt = 0;

void doCar(){
    // add counter
    cnt++;
    // add memory 
    garage = realloc(garage, sizeof(car) * cnt); // NOTE: not malloc
    printf("Enter the brand: ");
    scanf("%49s", garage[cnt - 1].brand); // or fgets
    printf("Enter the model: ");
    scanf("%49s", garage[cnt - 1].model); // or fgets
}

void ShowCars(){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s\n", garage[i].brand,  garage[i].model);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Add the `main` function to test:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // test for three cars
    doCar();
    doCar();
    doCar();
    ShowCars();

    // free memory after using
    free(garage);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but if i use the printf in the **doCar** function, works fine, but when i try to call the **ShowCars** Function, dont show notting

Answer (score 0):

In the function `ShowCars`, the line `printf("aqi= %s \n", (*garage + id).model);` you're dereferencing garage and adding `id` to that struct, which shouldn't make sense.  You're better off replacing that with the `garage[i]` notation that you had earlier, so like this:

```
printf("aqi= %s \n", garage[i].model);
```

Also, as someone else mentioned before, you need to allocate a new car of  `sizeof(struct car)` (which would be 50 + 50 = 100) and NOT `sizeof(struct car *)` (which is most likely on your system 4 for a 32-bit pointer size).  Lastly, each time you create a new car, you'll have to increment garage to point to these allocations.  Good luck!